# Which files are required on the root of an APFS partition?

Tags: filesystem, apfs

I have an external drive formatted as APFS. It contains folders such as `.PKInstallSandboxManager`, `.Spotlight-V100`, `.TemporaryItems`, `.Trashes`, and `.fseventsd`. Which of these files are safe to delete if I want to delete caches and clear up space? Are there any that are required for the file system to function?

Comment: These are not required files. 1 is for installing system updates and system application updates. 2 is for spotlight indexing. 3 is for temporary items. 4 is for storing the files in trash, 5 is a database of filesystem activity mainly used by Time Machine to speed up diff and thus decrease overall time.

Comment: Are any of these folders taking up significant space?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.PKInstallSandboxManager`: If it has much in it, you should be safe to remove the contents.

`.Spotlight-V100`: If this is consuming space and you don't want the file system indexed, disable indexing - don't delete.

`.TemporaryItems`: Safe to delete contents (and follow with a reboot),

`.Trashes`: Empty by deleting trash.

`.fseventsd`: Don't touch. It contains file system activity.

You don't mention, but you might also have:

`.DocumentRevisions-V100`: Used to maintain past versions of documents. Don't delete.